# OnSaveInstanceState insert DataSet var into Bundle

Tags: android, xamarin, dataset, bundle, onsaveinstancestate

Which method should I use for storing **DataSet** variable inside `OnSaveInstanceState`? There are different options like **PutArray**, **PutString**, **PutInt** etc. but I don't find a suitable option for datasets.

Comment: You mean `Android.Service.Autofill.Dataset`?

Comment: I mean System.Data.DataSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OnSaveInstanceState insert DataSet var into Bundle

Use `JSON.NET` package to serialize your `DataSet`, then you could use `PutString` to store this data in `Bundle`.

```
//Serialize DataSet 
System.String dataSet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);

//Deserialize DataSet
DataSet inPart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(dataSet);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I try it later and write feedback if it helped.

Comment: Yepp, works like a charm! Thank you @York Shen - MSFT

Comment: @bigb055, happy coding. :)

Answer (score -1):

make a pojo class and implement parcelable, then store to db ?